# JavaScript Loop only works once

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

```
var block = [];

setInterval(function() {

block.push(document.createElement("div"));
for (let i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
```

> I made a class in css that has some stylings

```
block[i].setAttribute("class", "block");
document.body.appendChild(block[i]);

}}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var block = [];

setInterval(function() {
  block.push(document.createElement("div"));

  for (let i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
    block[i].setAttribute("class", "block");
    document.body.appendChild(block[i]);
  }}, 1000);
```

The reason why it only runs once:
You only push one thing to the `block` array and on the for-loop, the `block.length` is 1 (because has only one item in it), which is true. Thus, it only gets run once.

According to your question, it sounds like you want to have a function execute a for-loop to update CSS styling.

Advice:
Just push all the item or div you wanna update to the `block` before the for-loop.